# Cloud9, open file from tree on single click?

Tags: c9.io

My question is pretty basic but I can't find anything on the user preferences (file or from the UI) inside the editor, or on the web about it.

I simply want the files to be opened when I click on them, not double click, but single click.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the "Enable Preview On Tree Selection" option under:

Cloud9->Preferences->User Settings->Tree & Navigate